# Error verifying the remote agent configuration 'vs-mda-remote test' fails with 'Error: not enough data'

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am following steps according to "Install Tools to Build for iOS" on msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx, to setup an iOS build.. 
On my Mac, I get the following error when I execute the "vs-mda-remote test" command..

```
Initializing self test for https
downloading cert for pin 390276
Downloading client cert for selftest from https://myMac:3000/certs/390276 to /Users/fred/remote-builds/selftest/selftest-client.pfx
pfxPath: /Users/fred/remote-builds/selftest/selftest-client.pfx
serverUrl: https://myMac:3000
buildUrl: https://myMac:3000/build/tasks?vcordova=4.1.2&cfg=release&command=build&options=--emulator
_tls_common.js:176
      c.context.loadPKCS12(pfx);
                ^
Error: not enough data
    at Error (native)
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:176:17)
    at Object.exports.connect (_tls_wrap.js:850:21)
    at Agent.createConnection (https.js:82:14)
    at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:194:16)
    at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:166:23)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:154:16)
    at Object.exports.request (http.js:49:10)
    at Object.exports.request (https.js:136:15)
    at Request.start (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/node_modules/request/request.js:674:30)
```

The server appears to be sending one..

```
vs-mda-remote
Copyright (C) 2014 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
0.2.7

Loading resources for language en from /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/resources/en/resources.json
Build Retention initialized with baseBuildDir /Users/fred/remote-builds/builds, maxBuildsToKeep 20
Initialized BuildManager with installedCordovaVersion: 4.1.2; baseBuildDir /Users/fred/remote-builds/builds; maxBuildsInQueue 10; deleteBuildsOnShutdown true; allowsEmulate true; nextBuildNumber 1479
ios-sim is installed on path at: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/vs-mda-remote/node_modules/ios-sim/build/release/ios-sim

Remote build server listening on [https] port 3000
GET /certs/390276 200 1ms - 3.51kb
```

Trouble shooting tried:
 - to ensure that iOS profiles and xCode developer certs exist - I tested that I can deploy a test app to an iPad.
- rerun install and checked every message to look for failure, none
- regenerated serverCert and clientCert multiple times

possibly linked
- the pfxPath is valid and a pfx does exist. (other issues around this issue indicate that a passphrase must be passed to the context object and I cannot find any passphrase being passed, but this code https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/joyent/node/.CommonJSPackage/node/.def/commonjs/lib/_tls_common.js/-/createSecureContext #176 seems to handle no passphrase..

Answer (score 2):

I've just had the same problem, but managed to figure it out - the following was configured Mac

1: Start the Server without TLS security

```
vs-mda-remote --secure false
```

2: Test the server (launch another terminal)

```
vs-mda-remote test --server http://localhost:3000
```

At this point - you shouldn't get any errors (this was failing here because the test mode seems to use TLS by default, and the only way to test with no security, is to manually specifiy the server URL)

3: Configure visual studio as per the documentation

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx

I have managed to get mine working great as of about 5 minutes ago using this. One point to make, in visual studio (2003 + CTP3.1) make sure you select iOS (to the right of the build mode drop down), if you don't select iOS then the iOS specific devices will not appear in the run list - sounds trivial, but it took me a few seconds scratching my head why I couldn't deploy to iOS remotely when I had Android build selected

Hope that helps you out!